How to create spotted bloom lines on chocolate?
The materials science of chocolate is fascinating, and I am curious about the bloom patterns on melted, then solidified chocolate discussed over on Physics SE and also shown in the photo below from a blog post by  Andrea Kamphuis and in a few other places online such as here, here, and here.

As discussed in "How can I cause (yes, cause, not prevent) bloom in chocolate?", it is easy to make chocolate bloom, but making the particularly interesting double-spot tracks doesn't seem so easy. I've failed in my first attempts.
Has anyone seen similar track patterns and can suggest any hints on how produce them?

It is just a guess, but I suspect a tool coated in a low melting point tool fat/oil dipped into the chocolate and dripped. Another possibility is a trail of seed crystals, perhaps very fine sugar?

Thanks for the suggestions @bob1.  I think the form of the tracks  - close-packed equal sized and spaced spots - would be hard to created by accidental drips from a tool.  A trail of seed crystals or very fine sugar is certainly a interesting possibility that I may try.

I was wondering if it was extra cocoa butter on a spatula and dragged through, but it goes up the sides too, so quite hard to replicate that way.
